# Can T4 read my model project and generate a file for each model?

Tags: t4

I'm not sure if I can do this, or I'm asking the correct way, but here goes.

I have a project with my models. Each model is it's own class in the assembly. I'd like a T4 template, in another project, that will go through each model, and output a file relating to it.

So, if I have 3 models, this T4 would output 3 files, one relating to each of the models. Then, if I add a 4th, the T4 would create the 4th related file.

Comment: Are you trying to do scaffolding (create the file from your model initially then change as need but never recreate, like MVC add view) or code generation (regenerate all the files each time you make a change, if you add a property to model and initiate the template run, the output file would be regenerated with the new property, like Entity Framework)?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to have 1 template which provides multiple output's.

http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template/

Comment: Can you override the filename generated?

Comment: @M Kenyon II : Either rename the sub-template for the individual output or output the content returned from the template generation process into code and save the file content any way you like